# prove that $\overline{H}=T\backslash (T\backslash H)^{\mathrm{o}}$

Tags: general-topology

I would like to prove that $\overline{H}=T\backslash (T\backslash H)^{\mathrm{o}}$

Where overline is closure and the o is interior.

Here is my attempt:

If $x\in \overline{H}$ then $x\notin T\backslash\overline{H}$. Since $T\backslash \overline{H}=(T\backslash H)^{\mathrm{o}}$ $\Rightarrow x\in T\backslash (T\backslash \overline{H})=T\backslash (T\backslash H)^{\mathrm{o}}$

Conversely, if $x\in(T\backslash H)^{\mathrm{o}}$ then $x\notin (T\backslash H)^{\mathrm{o}}$. Since $T\backslash(T\backslash H)^{\mathrm{o}}=T\backslash(T\backslash \overline{H})=\overline{H}\Rightarrow x\in \overline{H}$

Would this be correct?

Comment: What's T?  Why does T - closure H = interior (T - H)?

Comment: @WilliamElliot $T$ is the whole space/set. About the second one, isn't that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach, assuming that $T$ is the ambient topological space:

Recall that $\overline A$ is the smallest (wrt $\subset$) closed set which contains $A$, and $A^\circ$ is the largest open set contained in $A$.

In particular, $(T\setminus H)^\circ \subset (T\setminus H)$, so $T\setminus (T\setminus H)^\circ \supset H$. Since the LHS is closed, it follows that $T\setminus (T\setminus H)^\circ \supset \overline H$.

On the other hand, $H\subset\overline H$, so $T\setminus H\supset  T\setminus \overline H$. Since $T\setminus  \overline H$ is open, it follows that $(T\setminus H)^\circ \supset T\setminus \overline H$. But then $T\setminus (T\setminus H)^\circ\subset \overline H$.

Comment: but would my approach be sufficient? Or not rigourous enough?

Comment: You're using a few identities which you'd need to justify somehow.